# Advice on extracting data from JSON stream

Tags: php, json, stream

I have a JSON data stream which contains a bunch of JSON objects prefixed with the 'Data: ' label. What is the simplest way to make this valid JSON so I can utilise the data stream in an application? The URL given is constantly updating so it has no end.

Short snippet of some of the streamed data:

```
data: {"value":12,"id":"window_doneTodayCount_1","updatedAt":1646316313574}

data: {"value":"4:30","id":"window_averageTime_1","updatedAt":1646316313596}

data: {"value":"Tue 11:05","id":"window_lastUpdatedTime","updatedAt":1646316313746}
```

I am looking to convert this dynamically to something like the below, which would be valid and I can use within an app:

```
[{
        "value": 12,
        "id": "window_doneTodayCount_1",
        "updatedAt": 1646316313574
    },
    {
        "value": "4:30",
        "id": "window_averageTime_1",
        "updatedAt": 1646316313596
    }, {
        "value": "Tue 11:05",
        "id": "window_lastUpdatedTime",
        "updatedAt": 1646316313746
    }
]
```

Not even sure if this is possible as I have never seen a file like this.

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you working in? I would be looking to process this one line at a time. parse each block of JSON and push the resulting object into a collection, rather than assemble a JSON array.

Comment: The end result would be to get it into an iOS app, so Swift, but if I need to create a PHP file inbetween to process this, it would work. Just not worked with anything like this before, so not sure where to start. Thanks